# How to rename several layers at the same time?

Tags: qgis, gps, merge, tracking

I have got some GPS tracks (MultiLineString). As I import them to QGIS, they look like this:

[image: tracks]

I would like to merge them and to do so, I have to rename all of them like this (*picture 2*) otherwise an error occurs (all tracks become one single track at the same position).

[image: tracks2]

I usually give numbers as names (e.g. 01-200).
Sometimes I have only a few tracks but sometimes a lot.

Is it possible to rename all the tracks (layers) without renaming them one-by-one by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using the following in the **Python Console**:

```
x = 0

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    x = x + 1
    layer.setLayerName(str(x).zfill(2))
```

[image: Layer panel]

---

The `zfill()` command adds zeroes to the left of each layer name to fill the width.  You can specify this with the total number of layers you want to add. This helps with sorting the layers in order.

E.g. with `zfill(2)`:

```
1 = 01
9 = 09
```

With `zfill(3)`:

```
1 = 001
90 = 090
```

Comment: Should I use Python Console and write these to there? ( I am sorry, I am not familiar with these kind of expressions)

Comment: Yes, sorry should have mentioned. You can copy/paste the code from the answers provided into the Python Console =)

Comment: @Skye - Awesome, glad it works :)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas() 
allLayers = canvas.layers() 
i = 1

for bla in allLayers: 
    name = "layer_"+str(i)
    bla.setLayerName(name) 
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me for some reason =)

Comment: Not sure you can use `qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers()` for changing layer names. Your code works great if you use `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()` though :)

Comment: huh, strange. I tried it in a project just quickly before I postedd and it worked... but mapLayers().values() is the better option. I'll try again later in different project.  Would have to find out why ;)

Comment: definitely works for me; just for **visible** layers though. I'm a windows/QGis 2.12.0 user... [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/ukaaa802v/)

oh well, still your way seems to do the job for all layers; no matter if they are visible or not. 
`allLayers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
i = 1

for bla in allLayers: 
    name = "layerneu_"+str(i)
    bla.setLayerName(name) 
    i = i + 1`

Comment: Really sorry buddy, you are correct that your code does work for visible layers! That was a "Do'h!" on my part.

Comment: Haha, no worries. your way has the cool 00's and I think thats what Skye wanted ;)

Comment: Perhaps but atleast there's more than one method to answer the question which I always like. I've documented yours for future reference =)